# Config file in two locations on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

To try and fix a problem, somebody said "Edit XenCenterMain.exe.config" (doesn't matter why) but didn't say where the file was so I searched my hard drive and found it in two locations:

```
"C:\Users\rob.nicholson\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\XenCenter\XenCenterMain.exe.config"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\XenCenter\XenCenterMain.exe.config"
```

What's this VirtualStore all about in Windows 7? One of them appears to be a junction - right term? When I edit one of them, the other also updates.

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of [UAC Virtualisation](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx). This is to prevent non authorised users from writing to Program File and other sensitive location. You should be ok to just update the one in you app data folder.